# Laravel no carga las relaciones correctamente desde belongsTo

Tags: laravel, eloquent

A nivel de base de datos todos los usuarios tienen asignado un perfil, a la hora de consultar desde el modelo de perfil los usuarios los trae bien, pero a la hora de consultar desde el modelo de usuario los perfiles con **with()** carga sólo 1 relación por cada tipo de perfil y al resto no le carga nada.

User

```
public function Perfil(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Perfil','perfil_fk');
}
```

Perfil

```
public function Users(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\User','perfil_fk','id');
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Otras relaciones con usuario funcionan bien, inclusive las muchos a muchos, el modelo del usuario es el que genera por defecto la autenticación en laravel.

**El problema es con egaer loading** de momento he tenido que volver a hacer otra consulta para cargar el perfil, pero realmente necesito hacerlo con ->with()

```
$user->Perfil = Perfil::select('nombre','activo')->where('id', $user->perfil_fk)->get()[0];
```

En la base de datos si están relacionados las filas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

el problema es que tenes invertidas las relaciones y ademas creo estas usando una relacion `hasMany` que no corresponde, ya que un usuario deberia tener solo 1 perfil.
las tablas deberian de estar definidas así:

> **users:**
>       - id
>       - nombre
>       - ...
>   **perfiles:**
>       - id
>       - user_id
>       - ...

y los modelos

**User::class**
*Relación `One To One`*

```
public function perfil() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Perfil'); // por convencion busca el campo user_id
}
```

**Perfil::class**
*Relación `One To One` (inversa)*

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
}
```

y de esta forma al hacer tu consulta deberían de aparecerte los usuarios con su respectivo perfil.

```
User::with('perfil')->get()
```

Tenés muchos ejemplos en la [documentacion](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships) sobre este tema.

Comment: Las relaciones no están invertidas, el usuario sólo tiene un perfil mientras que perfil tiene muchos usuarios. Por eso el usuario es belongsTo de perfil y Perfil es hasMany de usuario. Y respecto a return $this->hasOne('App\Perfil'); , siempre se recomienda definir las claves para evitar  problemas de relaciones. ¿Alguna otra idea de que podría haber hecho mal?

Comment: Un perfil puede tener muchos usuarios? ok veo que interprete mal el concepto de perfil. Sería algo como tipo de usuario o me equivoco?  
Ya se donde debe estar el problema entonces.  Debés tener algun usuario sin id de perfil asignado.  fijate de hacer un User::whereNull('perfil_fk')->get() asi descartas que el problema sea ese. Podrías definir un valir por defecto para ese campo y te evitarias ese problema (si es que es ese)

Comment: Todo está relacionado, de hecho he consultado directamente en la base de datos a nivel de sql, pensando que algo podría generar un error al crear el foreign entre las tablas (Aunque no tenia mucho sentido, ya que de perfil puedo traer todos los usuarios, viceversa no). 
El where null me retorna una colecion vacía:  Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2874
     all: [],
   }

Comment: eso es bueno. Ahora la otra comprobacion sería si hay algun problema de inconsistencia de datos. Probá con esto `Usuario::whereNotIn('perfil_fk', Perfil::all()->pluck('id'))`

Comment: Igual me ha retornado una colección vacía Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2882
     all: [],
   }

Comment: es muy raro, ya probaste siguiendo las convenciones de laravel? quizá haya algo por ahi. Sino tambien podes probar con load() y con protected $appends. Son cosas que yo probaria pero la verdad que cuando pasan estas cosas generalmente es un error en la definicion de la relacion o en la consistencia de datos

Comment: hace un loop de esa coleccion haciendo un dump() de cada uno de los que no tienen perfil para detectar donde esta el problema

Comment: Ahora funciona mágicamente, no he cambiado nada respecto a lo inicial, anteriormente había purgado el cache en reiteradas ocasiones por lo cual lo descartaba, no sé que podría haber ocurrido dicho problema.
De todas formas muchas gracias por la ayuda Maru.